# Display product excerpt on cart page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm struggling to modify the cart page in woocommerce. I have the `cart.php` file in my theme folder, and I want to add some information about the products in that page.

I want to add two hooks:

- `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt`
- `woocommerce_template_single_meta`

But I'm not sure how to do it. I'm trying to add those hooks in some versions of the next basic code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents','matusevitch_cart_page_info' );
function matusevitch_cart_page_info(){
    // Your code
}
```

now in the function I tried either just to echo the hook, or to add it like this:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents','woocommerce_template_single_meta' );
```

I tried as well some solutions in other threads I checked before, but non of this works.

How can I display product excerpt for items on cart page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can simply be done this way for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_excerpt_in_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function add_excerpt_in_cart_item_name( $item_name,  $cart_item,  $cart_item_key ){
    $excerpt = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt($cart_item['product_id']), true );
    $style = ' style="font-size:14px; line-height:normal;"';
    $excerpt_html = '<br>
        <p name="short-description"'.$style.'>'.$excerpt.'</p>';

    return $item_name . $excerpt_html;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec and @SunilDora! both ways works well for me. I chose to add the code on the cart.php table, that way I had more control on the positioning. I'm trying as well to display the catagories and tags in the table. I have tried "get_post_meta($product_id);, but it didnt work..I tried as well with the wordpress "get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_tag')..any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again. I added the ` wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy )`, but the result at the page was just the word "Array". I didn't understand as for the foreach loop, if you ment the one that already exist in the 'cart.php' file , or to write another one?

Comment: @yod Yes it is an array of `WP_Term` objects, so you need to use it in a foreach loop this way: `foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat') as $term ){ echo $term->name; }` … it will output each term name for product categories in this case… for product tags you will use `wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag')` instead. You get it? … To get the term slug you will use `$term->slug` and for term Id `$term->term_id`…

Comment: yes! ok I understood now, everything works just fine:)
 thanks @LoicTheAztec !

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

override the following page template of woocommerce,

```
woocommerce/cart/cart.php in your theme
```

you will find a table HTML/code in it.

```
<th class="product-short-description"><?php _e('Short Description', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
//add this code in to <thead>..</thead>
<td class="product-short-description" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Product Excerpt', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
<?php
    echo get_the_excerpt($product_id);
?>
</td>
//add this code in to <tbody>..</tbody>
```

Hope this will helps you.